# Converting and printing Decimal of a char in C

Tags: c

After reading a single character as input, how do I determine what type of character it is? For example, how do I determine whether the character is a number, a letter or a dot?

Comment: The [`isXXX()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/is-isw-routines?view=msvc-170) function family can be classify a character as alpha, digit etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

- the function [`isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) to determine whether a character is a digit,
- the function [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) to determine whether a character is an alphabetic letter,
- the function [`ispunct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/ispunct) to determine whether a character is a punctuation mark,
- the function [`isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) to determine whether a character is a [whitespace character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character).

You can find a full list of all character classification functions of the C standard library [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification).

If you want to restrict the comparison to "a dot" (i.e. not any punctuation mark), then you can compare the value of the character directly with `'.'`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void )
{
    int c;

    printf( "Please enter a single character: " );
    c = getchar();

    if ( isdigit( c ) )
    {
        printf( "The input is a digit.\n" );
    }
    else if ( isalpha( c ) )
    {
        printf( "The input is an alphabetical letter.\n" );
    }
    else if ( c == '.' )
    {
        printf( "The input is a dot.\n" );
    }
    else if ( ispunct( c ) )
    {
        printf( "The input is a punctuation character.\n" );
    }
    else if ( isspace( c ) )
    {
        printf( "The input is a whitespace character.\n" );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "The input is not a digit, letter, punctuation or whitespace character.\n" );
    }
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
Please enter a single character: j
The input is an alphabetical letter.
```

```
Please enter a single character: 7
The input is a digit.
```

```
Please enter a single character: .
The input is a dot.
```

```
Please enter a single character: ;
The input is a punctuation character.
```

```
Please enter a single character:  
The input is a whitespace character.
```